# Log4j2 - ThreadLocal memory leak in ServletContextListener

Tags: java, tomcat, logging, memory-leaks, log4j2

I get the following error when shutting down Tomcat :

> SEVERE: The web application [App] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.PatternLayout$1] (value [org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.PatternLayout$1@14391aaf]) and a value of type [java.lang.StringBuilder] (value [2015-09-30 14:22:27.832 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR AppLogger - Error log.
>   ]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.

It appears only if I try to log something inside a contextInitialized or contextDestroyed method in a ServletContextListener implementation. Logging works fine in the rest of the app once Tomcat has started. I noticed the value of the StringBuilder is always the last entry logged.
In this case, the following code generates the log :

```
@Override
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent arg0)
{
    Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger("AppLogger");
    logger.error("Error log.");
}
```

After several hours of investigation (including SO), I still can't find an explanation. Is this a Log4j2 initialization problem? Is this a bug I should report?

I'm using Tomcat 8.0 in Eclipse 4.5

log4j-core-2.4, log4j-api-2.4, log4j-web-2.4 are in classpath.

web.xml is in 'WEB-INF'

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
   version="3.0">

<context-param>
    <param-name>log4jContextName</param-name>
    <param-value>App</param-value>
</context-param>

</web-app>
```

log4j2.xml is in 'src'

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration>
<!-- http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html -->
<Appenders>
    <File name="File" fileName="/home/user/app.log">
        <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
    </File>
    <Console name="Console">
        <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
    </Console>
</Appenders>
<Loggers>
    <Logger name="AppLogger" level="ALL">
        <AppenderRef ref="File"/>
    </Logger>
    <Root level="ALL">
        <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
    </Root>
</Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is related to a ThreadLocal [introduced in Log4j 2.4](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-1125). This was discovered after the release and [will be fixed](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-1142) in the next release, which will be either 2.4.1 or 2.5 (we hope this will be soon, in a week or two).